# Alias that runs a sub command

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I want to run 2 commands under an `alias`, but since it includes `cd` and I don't want to change folder from the main caller, I thought it may help calling a subcommand:

```
alias lhu="$(cd /my/path && myotherCommand)"
```

But when calling `lhu` it says `not found` (I already `source`d). How can I do this?

Comment: Try: `alias lhu="cd /my/path && myotherCommand"`

Comment: "and I don't want to change folder from the main caller"

Comment: In that case: `alias lhu="(cd /my/path && myotherCommand)"`.  [There is a big difference between `$(...)` and `(...)`.]

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
alias lhu="cd /my/path && myotherCommand && cd - "
```